# Xcode 10 "import" show completions only show current folder class, Is this a feature or a bug？

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[image]

Look at screenshot，`WeChatPayViewController.h` don't show completions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open "File"-->"Workspace Settings" and change the Option "Build System" to "Legacy Build System"

Answer (score 0):

Now, you should use relative path in 'New Build System'.
So, your code should be,

```
#import "../ViewController/WeChatPayViewController"
```

When you type this, Xcode will show completions.